# Can a user disable push notifications in such a way that onMessageReceived will not be called?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm considering using GCM notifications to implement a chat activity. Is it safe to use GCM to deliver the chat messages between users?

I have tested turning on 'Block all' notifications, but I'm still able to receive messages in `onMessageReceived` of my `GcmListenerService` and update my chat UI. It seems only the ability to show an actual toolbar notification has been disabled.

I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some other way for a user to "hard disable" push notifications in such a way that I won't even receive my `onMessageRecieved` call.

Comment: ya. disable/turn off background data for that app

Comment: Unfortunately not possible. but yes if you force to your server and tell don't send me any message for an `X` amount of time.

Comment: @MD I don't want the users to have the ability to disable onMessageReceived, so I'd say that's fortunate ha. So you are saying Jimit Patel is wrong, and turning off background data will still allow onMessageReceived to be hit?

Comment: @AdamJohns no Jimit is right. but i am talking about the case when your device connected to Internet and you don't want any Messgae come from GCM server

Comment: also note that some manufacturers (samsung) have been known to kill processes related to GCM to save battery so GCM isnt the end all be all

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is such an option, but you could always use a flag to check and execute its contents